# Are "many times", "a few times", "most days", etc. frequency adjuncts/adverbials? If so, of what type?

Tags: adverbs, adverbials, adjuncts, adverbial-phrases

Huddleston and Pullum (2002) divide frequency adjuncts/adverbials into bounding (how many times) and non-bounding (how often).  This is similar to Quirk et al's "definite" and "indefinite".  I will try to summarise the forms they (Huddleston and Pullum) list because I am confused on where "many times", "a few times", "most days", etc. may fit in.

A)  Bounding

1. Adverb - once and twice.  E.g. We met once.
2. NP - x time(s).  E.g. We met three times.
3. PP - on x occasion(s).  E.g. We met on four occasions.

B)  Non-bounding

1. Adverb - often, frequently, usually, regularly, ...  E.g. We met often.
2. NP with each/every + time noun, i.e. each/every day, ...  E.g. We met every day.
3. Bounding adverb + NP/PP, i.e. once a day, once per day, ...  E.g. We met once a day.
4. Idioms - off and on, on and off, ...

Note: first, the examples they give in the bounding category are all numerical (similar to Quirk et al); second, the only quantifiers they discuss in B2 are "each" and "every".

Where do phrases with other quantifiers fit?  "Many times" has the x time(s) form of the bounding category, but is synonymous with "often" or "frequently" in the non-bounding category.  (*We met many times.  ≡  We met often/frequently.*)  The same can be said about "a few times".  "Most days" is surely in the non-bounding category, but they have not listed a corresponding form.

Is their list incomplete?  Or are these not frequency adjuncts/adverbials?

Comment: I wouldn't call them "adjuncts", because that phrase has no commonly-accepted definition; consult your confessor about that. They certainly are quantifiers; CGEL's division seems to be between exact and approximate -- _5_ and _almost 5_. And the grammar is much more complex than you might suspect. Try McCawley 1993 to see about how quantifiers of all kinds should be parsed.

Comment: 'We met every day last month / during February 2021' is quasi-exact (there could have been two meetings etc on some days ... though Gricean maxims strongly suggest otherwise; one would want 'we met at least once every day last month'). I'm unsure about this subsetting strategem.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If by "I'm unsure about this subsetting strategem" you mean "What real-world problem would be solved by having definitive subcategorisation between bounding  and non-bounding frequency adjuncts/adverbials for the specific elements ***many times, a few times, most days,...***" then I totally agree!

Comment: I'd say the difference is between the numeral and the quantifier-related, as you suggest. Interestingly, though 'once' and 'twice' are bounding, 'once or twice' (idiomatic for 'a small number of times, non-zero') is then not.

Answer (score 0):

Bounding ~ having finite/defined limits; distinctly quantifiable.

Non-bounding ~ having indefinite/undefined limits; only indistinctly quantifiable

"Once, twice, etc. You know exactly how much/many, etc.

"Many times" has undefined limits -> it could be five, 5,000 or 5 million.

Comment: Interestingly, quantifiers do not relate to the distinctly quantifiable (denumerable) ... in fact, some are _fuzzy_ (a shedload / tons of).